# Webpack: Multiple entry points of different types (JS, HTML, LESS,...)

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

I would like to use webpack to package a Chrome Extension. To this end, I need to put together a bunch of JS files,

- `background.js`,
- `popup.js`,
- `content.js`,

and a few HTML and CSS files,

- `popup.html`,
- `popup.css`,
- `content.css`.

I figure I'll have to use multiple entry files, i.e.,

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    background: './src/scripts/background.js',
    content: './src/scripts/content.js',
    popup: './src/scripts/popup.js',
    html: './src/popup.html',
    ccss: './src/styles/content.less',
    pcss: './src/styles/popup.less',
  },
  // ...
}
```

With the loaders specified, e.g.,

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'file-loader' },
    { test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style!css!less' },
    // ...
    ],
}
```

However, I'm struggling with the `output` specifications. The JS files get bundled alright, but I'd like the HTML file to end up as HTML, too. With the standard

```
output: {
  path: './build/',
  filename: '[name].js',
},
```

this won't be the case since the `.js` is hardcoded.

Is there any way for JS, HTML, and CSS entry points to be output as JS, HTML, and CSS files, respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to include your HTML files in the webpack bundle, those will exist on their own.

As for bundling LESS/CSS, I recommend using the CSS and LESS loaders with the [extract text webpack plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin). This can be used to automatically bundle LESS/CSS modules that you import in your JavaScript modules, and then output that CSS bundle to the location of your choice.

So your webpack.config will look like this:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');    

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    background: './src/scripts/background.js',
    content: './src/scripts/content.js',
    popup: './src/scripts/popup.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: './build/',
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  loaders: [
    { test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style!css!less' },
    // ...
  ],
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
  ]
}
```

Then in your entry JS, require your LESS files:

```
require('./path/to/style.less');
```

All of your styles will be bundled to `./build/styles.css`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Can the `ExtractTextPlugin` spit out different CSS files for different input Less files, too?

Comment: the plugin will give you a CSS bundle for each entry JS file if you replace `style.css` with `[name].css`: `new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')`, I'll update my answer with this